# XSL creating fo-tables for inline-container results

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a situation where I need to display xml results (boolean, dates, i

I want to have the results display in a table and can't figure out a good way to go about this without a full rebuild of the entire process.

Here is an example of how I handle the boolean dataType. Each dataType is built off of the example below.

Here is the code to apply all the templates(Boolean, etc..). I am trying to figure out if I can create a Table display for the `apply-templates select="."`, or if I would need to edit every DataType to work with displaying into a table.

Comment: Where do `$adjustedWidth` and `$valueWidth` come from? Which formatter are you using? Some formatters, including AH Formatter, can do automatic table layout, which could mean that you wouldn't need to set column widths when creating a table.

Comment: I commented out that code, it's just to format the paramters with some indents for easier reading.<xsl:param name="indentLevel" select="number(0)" />
  <xsl:variable name="indent" select="$indentLevel * 0.25" />
  <xsl:variable name="adjustedWidth" select="$descWidth - $indent" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing is to not miss any levels in the `fo:table/fo:table-body/fo:table-row/fo:table-cell` hierarchy.

If I understand your code correctly, you want something like:

```
<fo:table>
  <fo:table-column column-width="{$adjustedWidth}in" />
  <fo:table-column column-width="{$adjustedWidth}in" />
  <fo:table-body>
    <xsl:for-each select="bml:Parameter[not(bml:ID='EndConditionMatrix' or
                                            bml:ID='PVATable' or
                                            bml:ParameterSubType='NoReport')]">
      <xsl:sort select="bml:SortOrder" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="bml:DataType='boolean']">
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paramCaption">
        <xsl:value-of select="$caption" />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paramValue">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="bml:Value/bml:ValueString='0'">No</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>Yes</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

That doesn't account for your `start-indent`, but it should get you some way towards what you want.

Comment: I will take a look at that way of formatting. I figured I might need to edit Each DataType for the table format instead of placing the DataTypes into a table through some <apply-Template="." code.

Comment: I do receive this error:  "fo:block" is not a valid child of "fo:table-body"! (No context info available)". I was running into this error before when trying to wrap a table around apply-templates=".". Any ideas?

Comment: As I said, you can't skip any of the table markup in XSL-FO: `fo:table-body` contains `fo:table-row`, which contains `fo:table-cell`, which contains `fo:block` (or similar) that contains your text.